# JQGrid IE8 Error: "12030 Unknown"

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jqgrid

I am building an application with a JQGrid.  When the JQGrid is loading, if I display errors, on IE 8, it will intermittently show:
    "Type: error; Response: 12030 Unknown"
and load no data.  FireFox and Chrome load the same grid with data just fine every time.  Sometimes IE 8 will load the data, and sometimes it will show the error.  I would say it is about 50/50 on initial load and 90/10 on page refreshes (it fails most of the time).  Has anyone else experienced this?  How did you resolve it?

Comment: I never seen the problem. Could you post (upload) the full example which can be used to reproduce the problem? Do you have the same problem in IE9? Which version of jQuery and jqGrid you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug w/ IE.  It looks like most versions of IE, lots of other people report it during ajax requests.  It looks like if  your request is a get it will work better than if it is a post.  On a post, it will tend to work the first time, and then quit working after that.  Here is an excellent answer:
http://old.nabble.com/AJAX-with-IE-and-method-POST-td20505105s27240.html